# ElasticSearch Error: MapperParsingException failed

Tags: elasticsearch

Received an error from elasticsearch. I try to insert the data from twitter into the ES. Some records sucessfully inserted, some are not. I'm new ES user. Using ES1.5

Error message as below:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:565)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:493)
at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndex(IndexShard.java:480)
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:192)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:515)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchParseException: Numeric value expected
at org.elasticsearch.common.geo.GeoUtils.parseGeoPoint(GeoUtils.java:406)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.GeoPointFieldMapper.parse(GeoPointFieldMapper.java:502)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeArray(ObjectMapper.java:602)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:489)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:554)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:487)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:554)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:487)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:554)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:487)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:544)
... 8 more
```

Comment: If you know which document fails to index, can you show it? As well can you show your mapping?

Comment: Cannot post document and mapping here because of the length limitation shortened links inside the documents. 
My failed doc: http://pastebin.com/KtY6a455
My mapping: http://pastebin.com/zKCVCCgH

Comment: Quite a mess in there :) It looks like you have a `bounding_box` object type declared to contain `coordinates` as double, but you're in fact feeding a GeoJSON structure. You should simplify your mapping

Comment: hehe... Can you guide me on how to simplify it. I'm ES newbie. Thanks.

Comment: The coordinates in bounding box was created by dynamic mapping once I insert the twitter data using location API. To avoid this error, what should I change to coordinates type. Any help please.

Comment: I've changed the coordinates data type from double to geo_point, but the same error still exist.